# LDAP - error 32 when authenticating

Tags: authentication, ldap

I'm not familiar with LDAP.

I have a user `binder`. I do not manage to log in with his credentials, I have an error code 32 (cf code below).

I use the docker image (osixia/openldap) with the default configuration.

I manage to log with `admin`.

Error code 32 seems to mean that the user doesn't exist but I can see him in the tree.

```
5a12e68e conn=1005 op=7 UNBIND
5a12e68e conn=1005 fd=16 closed
5a12e694 conn=1006 fd=16 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:41390     (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=0 BIND         dn="uid=binder,ou=Users,dc=toto,dc=software" method=128
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=0 BIND     dn="uid=binder,ou=Users,dc=toto,dc=software" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=1 SRCH base="" scope=0 deref=1 filter="    (objectClass=*)"
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=1 SRCH attr=1.1
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=2 SRCH base="" scope=0 deref=1 filter="    (objectClass=*)"
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=2 SRCH attr=subschemaSubentry
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=2 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=3 SRCH base="cn=Subschema" scope=0 deref=1     filter="(objectClass=*)"
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=3 SRCH attr=attributeTypes objectClasses     matchingRules ldapSyntaxes *
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=3 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=4 SRCH base="" scope=0 deref=1 filter="    (objectClass=*)"
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=4 SRCH attr=namingContexts
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=4 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=5 SRCH base="dc=toto,dc=software" scope=1     deref=2 filter="(objectClass=*)"
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=5 SRCH attr=objectclass
5a12e694 conn=1006 op=5 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=32 nentries=0 text=
5a12e69c conn=1006 op=6 SRCH base="dc=toto,dc=software" scope=0     deref=2 filter="(objectClass=*)"
5a12e69c conn=1006 op=6 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=32 nentries=0 text=
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: 'Error code 32 seems to mean that the user doesn't exist' *or* that the password was incorrect.

Comment: Wrong... Error 32 means that the base DN of the search request doesn't exist. In your case "dc=toto,dc=software" doesn't exist and reading it, or searching for all its child entries is not possible. During a Bind request, there should never be an error code 32 returned, but invalid credentials.